# Use types of same name & namespace in 2 .NET assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, namespaces, assembly-resolution

Out of curiosity, I've created 2 assemblies which both have a class (`Class1`) with the exact same namespace (`Library1`).  I then create another client referencing those 2 assemblies and try to create an instance of `Class1`.

The compiler, not surprisingly, gives me a compile-error about the ambiguous reference.  Is there any way to explicitly specify the type in the assembly I want to use to avoid the ambiguity?

Note: I know this rarely, if ever at all, happens in practice.  It's just a question out of curiosity about language feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should use an [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) to wrap the assembly namespaces outside of the Global namespace. Here's how:

1. In the project that references the 2 assemblies, select one of them under References, and in the Properties window change the Aliases value from `global` to, say, `global, Library1a`.
2. Do the same for the the other reference, but give it a different alias-- let's go with `global, Library1b` for our example.
3. Insert `extern alias Library1a;` and/or `extern alias Library1b;` as the first 2 lines of any classes that consume the assemblies.
4. When accessing ambiguous members, qualify the namespace with `Library1a.` or `Library1b.`. Examples: `Library1a.Library1.Class1...` `Library1b.Library1.Class1...`

Answer (score 1):

It happens in practice and is a real pain, the external alias can't always solve the problem. Here's one example of where it's an issue: [Duplicate Namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453451/resolving-extension-methods-linq-ambiguity).