# MonoGame ModelProcessor

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, content-pipeline

Is there a MonoGame's equivalent of XNA's [`ModelProcessor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.content.pipeline.processors.modelprocessor.aspx)?

I am using a custom `AnimatorProcessor` class, derived from `ModelProcessor`, similar to what's done in the ["better skinned sample"](http://metlab.cse.msu.edu/betterskinned.html):

```
[ContentProcessor(DisplayName = "Animation Processor")]
public class AnimationProcessor : ModelProcessor
{
    // custom stuff
}
```

I am now trying to port this code to MonoGame, but it seems that (although MonoGame recently got its own pipeline) there is no `ModelProcessor` class in MonoGame pipeline projects.

I could use XNA pipeline, but the issue is then that all the model content classes use actual XNA classes/structs (vectors, quaternions), which reside in exactly the same namespace as MonoGame's, creating compile time conflicts in my main project. Meaning that I should map these classes from one assembly (XNA) to the other one (MonoGame), which is [rather fugly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067550/use-types-of-same-name-namespace-in-2-net-assemblies).

**(Update)**

I realized that MonoGame indeed has a `ModelProcessor` inside its `MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline` assembly, but then there is an additional `MonoGame.ContentPipeline` assembly (for which I am not sure if it's obsolete, or still has to be used within the pipeline).

But if I rebuild my `AnimationProcessor` to use the MonoGame's `ModelProcessor`, then Visual Studio cannot use it to import/process my fbx file. Building the content project fails with `"Cannot find content processor 'AnimationProcessor'"`, and it's not even offered as an option in the drop down box for .fbx file (probably because Visual Studio looks for classes derived from XNA's processors, and it doesn't care for MonoGame).

Does anyone know how I should import the fbx content using a custom processor, and still have MonoGame classes instead of XNA's?

Comment: I think this should be moved to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

MonoGame has its own content pipeline now. So what you really need to do is port your custom processors over to a new library which references the MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline assembly. This library will then be compatible with the Pipeline tool.

You can find the documentation on this at http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=Using_The_Pipeline_Tool. Specifically look at the section for Custom Content Processors.

Comment: Thanks for the information, since we were in a hurry to end the project, we ended up duplicating files from our previous projects targeting XNA into the new project. But the problem is that if we rebuild a custom  `AnimationProcessor` to use the MonoGame's `ModelProcessor`, then I cannot select it as the processor for fbx files in Visual Studio.