# Ambiguous call for context.Object.Include

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating a scaffold controller in MVC with Entity Framework.
my model contains a navigation property and i expect to get eager loading for this property in the generated controller.
and i get exactly what  I expects, but there is an error to ambiguous call in

```
var courses = db.Courses.Include(c => c.Department);
```

the error details

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' and 'System.Linq.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)

any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving extension methods/linq ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453451/resolving-extension-methods-linq-ambiguity)

Comment: `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`, really?

Comment: @mattytommo i don't think that is the same as my problem

Comment: @GertArnold this is copy from the error i got in vs

Comment: @MohamedBadr It is, you've created an ambiguity between those two methods so you need some way of distinguishing between the two, which you can use aliases to do.

Comment: @mattytommo i didn't create any methods yet, the controller is generated with this code and this error

Comment: I think you also reference a pre-release of EF7.

Comment: @GertArnold actually a pre-release of EF7 was installed by mistake but it's already un-installed and i'm using EF6 now, and everything was working just fine until i hit this error

Comment: @MohamedBadr It's probably left the DLLs in the bin folder, make sure you delete those. Just seen your answer after I wrote that, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@GertArnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) as he gave me a clue

EF7 was installed and replaced with EF6, but i think that some refrenced dll wasn't comletely removed so i uninstalled EF6 and manulaly deleted all dll files related to entity framework also deleted any refrenced file related to EF in the project then reinstaleed EF6 again
and it works fine